# jquery validator - required fields not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form class="myForm" method="post" action="/" >
 <input type="text"   name="number" class="form-control">
 <input type="text"  name="amount"  class="form-control send">
 <input type="text"  name="operator" class="form-control send">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Jquery validator:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#myForm").validate({
        debug: true,
        groups: {  // consolidate messages into one
            names: "amount operator"
        },
        rules: {
            number:"required",
             amount: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".send"]
            },
            operator: {
                require_from_group: [1, ".send"]
            }

        },
        messages: {
               number: "required."

        }

    });
   jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        require_from_group: jQuery.format("amount or bundle should be filled")
    });
});
```

**problem**

Here **number required** is not working after groups is added.
**if groups removed its working.**

Comment: It's impossible that any of this would be working.  Your `.validate()` is attached to an `id` selector and your `<form>` does not even contain an `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code that you posted, it's impossible that any of this could be working.  Your `.validate()` method is attached to an `id` selector when your `<form>` does not contain an `id`.

---

An `id` selector does not match a `class`...

```
<form class="myForm" ....
```

But you're using an `id` selector...

```
$('#myForm') ....
```

Attach a class selector to `.validate()`, `$('.myForm')`, or add an `id` attribute, `id="myForm"`, to your `<form>`.

---

FYI, the `require_from_group` method is part of the `additional-methods.js` file, so if you haven't already included this, it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to not use jQuery validator but do something like this:

```
<form class="myForm" method="post" action="/" >
 <input type="text"   name="number" class="form-control"required="required">

 <input type="text"  name="amount"  class="form-control "required="required">

 <input type="text"  name="operator" class="form-control "required="required">

 <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```